# Grid View in Asp.net C# with wamp Server's MYSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, gridview, wamp

I want to show my data in grid view in my Asp.new c# form.
I am using Wamp Server's MySQL database.
I have tired a lot for binding database with grid view.
Please do help.

my code  :

```
      public partial class Temp : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AASProject"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();

        gvFoodDetail.RowEditing+= new GridViewEditEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowEditing);
        gvFoodDetail.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowDeleting);
        gvFoodDetail.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowUpdating);
        //gvFoodDetail_RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventArgs(gv);
       // gvFoodDetail.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowEditing);
       // gvFoodDetail.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowDeleting);
       // gvFoodDetail.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowUpdating);
       // gvFoodDetail.RowCancelingEdit += new GridViewCancelEditEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_RowCancelingEdit);

        gvFoodDetail.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gvFoodDetail_PageIndexChanging);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvFoodDetail.Visible = true;
            loadFoodDB();
        }

    }
    public void loadFoodDB()
    {

        string getFoodDetails = "Select Emp_ID,intime,outtime,date From datetime";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getFoodDetails, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        gvFoodDetail.DataSource = dt;
        gvFoodDetail.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: I have implemented grid view without database .It is working perfact.I have connected database successfullly as well.

Comment: Can you show your code so far?  For connecting to the database *and* for the `GridView`?

Comment: show some code and we will help you from there

Comment: @jadarnel27-I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datagridview.Datasource = datasource
datagridview.databind()
```

This should set and show the data. You have to handle the columns and everything manually or automatically.